# Некорректно отрабатывает JS код в Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Есть такой код:

```
var fileinput = input.get(0);
var timestamp = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);
var name = 'screenshot_' + addFile.nextAttachmentId + '_' + timestamp + ext;
var blob = clipboardData.items[file].getAsFile(); //clipboardData.items[file] is a DataTransferItem Object
blob.name = name;
uploadAndAttachFiles([blob], fileinput);
```

В Firefox 50.1.0 строчка `blob.name = name;` почему-то отрабатывает некорректно, присваивание не отрабатывает, в `blob.name` остается такое название: `изображение.png` вместо сгенерированного `name`, в итоге в функцию `uploadAndAttachFiles([blob], fileinput);` попадает объект такого содержания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем в Chrome 55.0.2883 все работает отлично:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем может быть связана проблема? И откуда берется название "изображение.png"?

Comment: Некорректно работает как раз хром. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Properties https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-attrs `File.name` — readonly

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а каким образом в Firefox тогда просунуть ему новое имя? Не могу понять откуда вообще берется "изображение.png"?

Comment: Можно создать новый `File`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, можно какой-нибудь пример?